# String of ints to list python

Tags: python, string, list, int

I have the following string:

```
  string =  '['1', '2', '3']'
```

I would like to make this into a list of ints so I can add each int together in the list to get an output of 6

I currently have this code:

```
stripQuotes = ", ".join(string)
intList =[stripQuotes]
map(int, intList)
print(intList)
```

but I get an output of:

```
['1, 2, 3']
```

instead of:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: this `string =  '['1', '2', '3']'` will throw `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: ... And if you fix that SyntaxError by changing the first and last apostrophes to quote marks, then your code still crashes with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "[, ', 1, ', ,,  , ', 2, ', ,,  , ', 3, ', ]"`. I don't think this is the code that's producing that output.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use regex :

> Short:

```
import re
string =  """'['1' ,'2', '3']'"""
pattern=r'(\d.*?)'


match=re.finditer(pattern,string)
print([int(integer.group()) for integer in match])
```

> Detailed:

```
import re
string =  """'['1' ,'2', '3']'"""

pattern=r'(\d.*?)'


int_list=[]
match=re.finditer(pattern,string)
for integer in match:
    int_list.append(int(integer.group()))

print(int_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and as you said:

> so I can add each int together in the list to get an output of 6

then:

```
print(sum([int(integer.group()) for integer in match]))
```

output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping the inner string which will result in an error. You'd either replace the outside quotes by double quotes: `"['1', '2', '3']"` or you could escape the inner quotes like so: `'[\'1\', \'2\', \'3\']'` (personally I prefer the first one)

```
from ast import literal_eval

string = "['1', '2', '3']"
int_list = [int(i) for i in literal_eval(string)]
print(int_list)
```

Then you would just use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to sum the elements in your list:

```
sum(int_list)
```

check out the doc on [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 0):

You can eval :

```
listofstrings=eval(strings)
ints= [int(k) for k in listofstrings]
```

a safer way to do this if you want input security (I never sleep at night if I run eval) :

```
elems= strings.split("'")
ints=[]
for k in elems:
    try:
        ints+=int(k)
```

Comment: I recommend using https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval instead of eval.

Comment: ... 5 seconds late

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the string list to integer list

```
strList =  ['1', '2', '3']
intList = [int(i) for i in strList]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a map function to solve this. For example:

Python 2.x:

```
string = "['1', '2', '3']"
map(int, eval(string))
[1,2,3]
```

Python 3.x:

```
string = "['1', '2', '3']"
list(map(int, eval(string)))
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: This will still throw an error. You are not escaping the inner quotes. use `"['1', '2', '3']"` instead

Comment: Yes, I've tested this, but I copied the string object from the original question! That'll teach me next time. Now it should work, at least in python 2.x

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code

```
s1 = "['1', '2', '3']"    
print(sum([int(x) for x in list(s1) if x.isnumeric()]))
```

that will output
6

Comment: `str` objects do not have an `isnumeric` method. `isnumeric` is only available for unicode objects

Comment: I suppose you are in python2. This works in python3. So "This will not work" is misleading.